# Change a string in c++ after is has been printed out onto the screen

Tags: c++, string

I have a string i want to change after it has been printed out onto the screen.

```
    string str = "Calculating..."
    string str2 = "Results:"

    cout << str << endl;   //this prints out 

    /*then later on in the program I want to OVERWRITE the string printed on the screen with str2
*/
```

Note: I am not looking to replace that variable which holds the definition of the string but looking to replace the output on the screen.

Comment: system("clear") on linux or system("cls") on windows ?

Comment: So, what's your console?

Comment: P.S. I already have output on my console so i dont want to clear the whole screen

Comment: What kind of console?  A windows command prompt console?  Linux?  Network connection to something?

Comment: @LearnerBeware Not every console is capable of doing this. For example, a line printer clearly isn't. Whether or not this is possible and how to do it depends on the platform and console type. This question isn't about C++ or strings, it's about some particular platform's console support or some particular console.

Answer (score 4):

For many consoles, you can <strike>erase</strike> overwrite the last line in the console using `'\r'`.

For a more general and portable approach you should use a terminal control library such as [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)).

Comment: You can overwrite, but you can't erase unless it is a smart terminal (vt100 family, etc.).  Be sure to pad with trailing blanks to "erase".

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    for(int i = 1;i <= 10;i++){
        cout << i;
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
        cout << "\r";
        fflush(stdout);
    } 
}
```

if you're using linux, I think this code gonna work.
use '\r' character to delete and don't forget to flush the buffer

Comment: Is there an alternative for Windows?